# Rails 5.1.3 API using Devise Auth Token custom rendering

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm developing an API using Rails 5.1.3 and I'm using the gem `devise_token_auth` for authenticate. Everything was working fine until I needed to customize the JSON renderized after an error occurred, like the client sending an request with an invalid email.

So, to do this, I redefined my routes from

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
```

to

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
  registrations: 'devise/registrations'
}
```

and created a file `app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb` as below:

```
class RegistrationController < DeviseAuthToken::RegistrationController
  def render_create_error
    render 'devise/registrations/create_error.json'
  end

  def render_create_success
    super
  end
end
```

Now all requests that depends of `RegistrationController` are getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #<#<Class:0x007f84cfab70d8>:0x007f84cec53e10>
```

What I should do to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on my rails server (rails 6). I have created folders called overrides where I place all my custom controllers / views

**routes.rb**

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
    registrations: 'overrides/registrations'
}
```

**app/controllers/overrides/registrations_controller.rb**

```
module Overrides
  class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
    def render_create_success
      render partial: 'overrides/registrations/render_create_success.json.jbuilder'
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/overrides/registrations/_render_create_success.json.jbuilder**

```
json.status 'success'
json.data do
  json.extract! @resource, :field1, :field2, etc.
end
```